# Permission Error: [errorno 13] permission denied C:\\windows\\system 32 \drives\\etc

Tags: python

I have made a patron code to block some websites during a certain time , and I have tested it in command line and it worked ,  I want to run it as a background process , I run the code in command line as administrator  to be able to write in hosts file , but the output of the command line is : Permission Error:[error13] permission denied  C:\windows\system32\drives\etc, and I 'm sure I write the right path
So , please !  any good idea to fixed it

Comment: `permission denied C:\windows\system32\drives\etc` That is not a hosts file.  What exactly are you trying to write?

Comment: Please, be also aware that for x86_64 arch you need to run Python with the same arch to find a file. I'm not sure if the whole process tree should be x86_64 or not.